# Mobile Safari Scroll to bottom to load more content like Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, mobile-safari

I'm a newbie in web development.

My teammate and I are working on a project where say, 10 items are initially shown on the page. The user can scroll the list of items and when he reaches the bottom, it should load 5 more contents. In addition, we want the list to stay on the items that were last viewed before the loading of more contents was done; but, it should still support loading of new updates on top of the page - like that in the Facebook news feeds. While it's loading more contents when scrolling reaches the bottom of the page, new updates are added above.

Our app is working smoothly on desktop browsers, but we're having issues on the mobile side, specifically on Mobile Safari. Scrolling to the bottom is working. It loads more contents, so as handling new updates on top of the page; however it brings the user back to the top of the list, instead of staying on the last items shown and the newly loaded contents would be hidden and will be viewed once scrolled downwards. So, if page is showing the 11th-20th items on the list, and he scrolls down to load more, say 5 items, the page reloads and brings the user to the 1st-10th item. It should stay on the 11th-20th items, but still has loaded the 21st-25th items hidden below, instead.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the third party libraries as this one for an example http://dcarrith.github.com/jquery.mobile.lazyloader/

Comment: What our app has right now is that the mobile tends to reload the page, that is why the user is sent back to the top of the page. I've edited my question above with details that the listview should also support adding new pushed updates on top of the page like what Facebook has.

Comment: I appreciate your effort for helping, so I'm going to give you an up vote. :)

Comment: We decided to use the default scroll instead...and it works great on our app. Thanks again for the help...though I didn't use your answer...I know I can still use it for future references... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using iScroll 4, it should achieve what you wish for mobile
http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/pull-to-refresh/

Comment: IMHO, iScroll is the worse enemy to jQuery Mobile. I've tried on various projects and it will behave odd on various devices.

Comment: iScroll isn't exactly the answer that I'm looking for. But thank you for your effort. :)